# Maximal Lie subalgebra of $sl_n$

Tags: lie-algebras

How to find the maximal solvable Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak sl(n,\mathbb R)$?

Maybe the invariance lemma is the key!

Answer (score 1):

Note that a maximal solvable subalgebra need not be unique. For simplicity take $n=2$. So in $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ we have several maximal solvable subalgebras, e.g., $\mathfrak{a}=\langle h,x\rangle$, or $\mathfrak{b}=\langle h,y\rangle$. Here $(x,y,z)$ is a basis with brackets $[x,y]=h,\,[[h,x]=2x,\,[h,y]=2y$. In general, a maximal solvable subalgebra is called a *Borel subalgebra*. Over the complex numbers they a re all conjugated. The so-called *standard Borel subalgebra* can be constructed via the weight space decomposition:

*Proposition* Let $L$ be a semisimple Lie algebra, and $H$ be a Cartan subalgebra with root system $\Phi$ and base $\Delta$. Then the standard Borel subalgebra is given by
$$
B:=B(\Delta)=H\oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha\in \Phi^+} L_{\alpha}.
$$
In terms of matrices, the standard Borel subalgebra of $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$ consists of the solvable Lie subalgebra of all upper-triangular matrices in 
$\mathfrak{sl}(n)$.

Comment: Thanks Dietrich, actually I am still not familiar with the root system. I am sorry I asked a very general question about maximal solvable subalgebras which I learned from you that they are not unique.. Can I ask a specific question that: prove that $t(n, F) ∩ sl(n, F)$ is a maximal
solvable subalgebra of $sl(n, F)$?

Comment: I can add this specific question to the main question and you may add the answer to your answer and we get a complete answer

Comment: $t(n,F)\cap \mathfrak{sl}(n,F)$ just consists of all traceless upper-triangular matrices, hence *is* the standard Borel subalgebra. So it is maximal solvable (sorry for using again Lie algebra theory, but that's the way you should try it, I think).

Comment: I think I will. Do you have a good and simple reference about this.. Like the link you provided about Heisenberg Algebras?

Comment: Hmm, yes - my [lecture notes](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_28_lie_algebra_course.pdf). OK, this was a joke. You want this in Hindi, I guess, not in German. But of course, there are nice lecture notes in English, too.

Comment: No it's fine,, I know some German :-)

Comment: By the way, there is a hint on this question: Use $H$ to produce, out of opposite weights, a copy of $sl(2, F)$ inside a supposed larger subalgebra. .. But I didn't understand it!